# Why I should check for 'if id is not None' in this code?

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial entitled Raw Delete Class Based View, Raw Update, list and detail Class Based View respectively. I grasp everything save one.

in `course_list.html` I have the following link:

```
<a class="delete-btn" href="{% url 'courses:course-delete' obj.id %}">Delete</a>
```

If user clicks and confirm deletion, it will delete that course from list of courses.

The question is why the instructor is checking for `if id is not None:`?  even **if he omit that from code, it will still work fine**. Moreover, **there're zero chances for 'id' to be None**, since the user clicks on a form like this below and the link will guide the user to a specific route which finally deletes that specific course. Please help me understand this!

[image]

This is the code:

```
class CourseDeleteView(View):
    template_name = "course/course-delete.html"

    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = None
        if id is not None:  # why would he do that?
            obj = get_object_or_404(Course, id=id)
        return obj

    def get(self, request, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:    # here, why checking obj for not None?
            context['object'] = obj
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, id=None,  *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:  # and here
            obj.delete()
            context['object'] = None
            return redirect('/course/')
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Thank you in advance

edit: urls.py

```
app_name = 'courses'
urlpatterns = [
    path('courses/<int:id>/delete/',
         CourseDeleteView.as_view(), name='course-delete'),
]
```

Comment: What's your url?

Comment: I just added that in question

Comment: Here `get_object_or_404` completely making sense, but I don't think without having id you can reach into your code.

Comment: My guess is that if someone enters a url for an invalid `id`, or tries to access a deleted object, it will protect the routines because there isn't an object to manipulate anymore - this would throw errors. Granted, the Python way to do it would be using "`try`/`except`" instead of `if` checking.

Comment: @lucasgcb `get_object_or_404` is capable of taking care of this scenario. if the object is deleted it'll throw a 404.

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking time and helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any reason to do so, if `id` is `None` then `get_object_or_404`will raise `Http404`.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) is clear about this:

> The following example gets the object with the primary key of 1 from `MyModel`:
>
> ```
> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
>
> def my_view(request):
>     obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
> ```
>
> This example is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> from django.http import Http404
>
> def my_view(request):
>     try:
>         obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
>     except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
>         raise Http404("No MyModel matches the given query.")
> ```

Comment: Thank you Jacques Gaudin, God bless you. I will ignore checking id for none.

Answer (score 0):

In general, writing conditions like this are good practice, because you want to ensure that your code never fails. In a web application, it's even more important because URLs can be accessed from anywhere.

In this particular example, you're right, the route itself will fail if the ID is not present. However, if we restructure the id to be a query param (like `/courses/delete?id=x`), then that part of the code becomes necessary.

Basically, it's a [sanity check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check).